# How to use logger in Groovy with soapui?

Tags: groovy, soapui

i'm trying to test logger with Grroovy in Soapui and i added the apache-logging-log4j in C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\ext

Do i have to add more libraries here?

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
import org.apache.log4j.Level

@Log4j
class Log4jLoggerClass
{
   Log4jLoggerClass()
   {
      // It is necessary to set logging level here because default is FATAL and
      // we are not using a Log4j external configuration file in this example
      log.setLevel(Level.INFO)
      println "\nLog4j Logging (${log.name}: ${log.class}):"
      log.info "${this.printAndReturnValue(1)}"
      log.debug "${this.printAndReturnValue(2)}"
   }

   public String printAndReturnValue(int newValue)
   {
      println "Log4j: Print method invoked for ${newValue}"
      return "Log4j: ${newValue}"
   }
}
```

and i have this following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: 
No signature of method: Log4jLoggerClass.main() is applicable for argument types: 
([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]] 
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), any(), find(), wait(long, int), print(java.lang.Object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this error has anything to do with Log4J. I don't know what Soapui is, but judging by the error message, it appears your class is expected to have a main method. What happens if you add this method to `Log4jLoggerClass`?

```
static void main(String[] args) {
  println "main method invoked"
}
```

### Update

In response to your comment below, I guess the reason you're not seeing any logs on the console is because you don't have a console appender configured. Normally you configure Log4J with a configuration file that specifies the log level and appenders to use for various namespaces. An appender (roughly) defines a place where the logs are sent to, so a console appender sends the logs to the console, a file appender stores them in a file, etc. If you add a Log4J configuration file to your project, you can define the appenders and log levels you want to use declaratively, i.e. you can remove the statement `log.setLevel(Level.INFO)`

Comment: I added at the end of the code, now there is no error message but i don't see any message in console output, i use saopui 5.0.0 open source version

Comment: yes it 's inthe soapui-log4j.xml file, everything is configured